# Backbone.js: Update Collection with different data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone Collection of Models that have different data coming in on page load than when it's fetched.

For example, the attributes coming in on page load are:

```
[{ name: 'cat', color: 'yellow' },
 { name: 'dog', color: 'brown' },
 { name: 'fish', color: 'orange' }]
```

Then, on fetch() (or otherwise updated from the server while the page lives, the data looks like:

```
[{ name: 'cat', current: 5, total: 100 },
 { name: 'dog', current: 6, total: 50 },
 { name: 'fish', current:7, total: 25 }]
```

How can I update the Backbone Collection with the new data while retaining the old data? IDs are not assigned from the server (name is guaranteed unique).

Comment: Define "retain". Do you mean save the old data into some variable? Or more keep both the old and new data in the same collection instance?

Comment: The latter (keep both the old and new data in the same collection instance)

Comment: then doesn't the built-in `fetch()` do what you want? [From the docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch): *If you'd like to add the incoming models to the current collection, instead of replacing the collection's contents, pass `{add: true}` as an option to fetch.*

Comment: @CrescentFresh But fetch don't update/add any models with id that yet exist. So a collection from the question just will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with this. This will update the properties for models that exist while also removing models that did not come in and adding new ones.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.update = function(col_in){  
  var self = this,
      new_models = [];

  _(col_in).each(function(mod_in) {
    var new_model = self._prepareModel(mod_in),
        mod = self.get(new_model.id);
    if (mod) { 
      new_models.push(mod.set(mod_in, {silent:true}));
    } else { 
      new_models.push(mod_in);
    }
  });

  this.reset(new_models);
};
```

Note the use of `_prepareModel` this is important so that the Models can be identified via whatever "id" property is used in the Backbone Model object.